# MailJet: HTTP POST status code 200 but email sending is blocked

Tags: c#, mailjet

I am using the following C# code following the "Send a mail" [example here](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-dotnet) to send an email with MailJet using a template. The template has a variable `{{var:name}}` which is the name of the recipient.

```
int templateID = 610379;

MailjetRequest request = new MailjetRequest
{
    Resource = Send.Resource,
}
.Property(Send.FromEmail, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailJetFromEmail"].ToString())
.Property(Send.FromName, "Support Team")
.Property(Send.MjTemplateID, templateID)
.Property(Send.MjTemplateLanguage, true)
.Property(Send.Vars, new JArray
{
    new JObject
    {
        { "name", "Name of the customer"}
    }
})
.Property(Send.Recipients, new JArray
{
    new JObject
    {
        { "Email", "testemailtosend@gmail.com" }
    }
});

MailjetResponse response = await client.PostAsync(request);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // Log success
}
else
{
    // Log error
}
```

While `response.IsStatusSuccessCode` does equal `true`, my email is consistently getting blocked. **Can someone please explain why the email is getting blocked and how to fix it?**

[image]

Comment: What does "blocked" mean?

Comment: I had a look at the mailjet docs and it seems to me that 200 means that the Mailijet system accepted the e-mail, not that it was sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I actually had multiple Variables in the email template, but was only specifying one of them. (This was confusing to me because I did set default values for those other variables, but it turns out that MailJet only sends the email if ALL of the variables' values have been specified)

This

```
.Property(Send.Vars, new JArray
{
    new JObject
    {
        { "name", "Name of the customer" }
    }
})
```

should have been this

```
.Property(Send.Vars, new JArray
{
    new JObject
    {
        { "name", "Name of the customer" }
        { "org", "Organization of the customer" }
    }
})
```

because the other variable in the email template was the organization.

Answer (score 0):

Many email servers will "block" when a `subject` is not present.

Comment: However, the subject is already a part of the template. I don't think I should need to specify it again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the provided **FromEmail** value was **not present** or **activated** in the Mailjet **Dashboard -> Setup Domain Authentication -> Addresses**. For this reason, the response was 200 although the Mailjet service blocked my email.

That's why I didn't receive the mail.